# Is "torture something back" a phrase?

Tags: meaning, grammar

I was watching the Vampire Diaries series and in episode 20 of season 4, Damon says:

> How hungry does she have to be before we can ***torture*** some feelings *back into her*?

I can't get the grammar of this sentence! Is torture something back into someone a phrase? Would you please explain it?

Comment: *torture* has been “verbed” here.

Comment: It is not _torture back_ but _back into her_ as in: The feelings have gone missing and to bring back at least pain we could use torture.

Comment: @Jim - to torture is a verb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means *bring some feelings back into her **by torture***. Basically he says that only by torture she can be forced to become human again.

***Torture*** is a noun used as a verb here, and this is called ***[verbing](https://www.thoughtco.com/verbing-definition-1692587)***. Verbing can be informal and very handy in speech. With one word you say many:

> - She was ***marmalading*** a scone with Chivers Rough Cut.
>    (Martha Grimes, *The Lamorna Wink. Viking*, 1999) 
>   <sub>*(instead of **spreading marmalade on**)*</sub>
> - I like your verbs that are things. I think I'm gonna ***sandwich*** after I ***sofa*** here for a bit.
>   (*My Boys*, 2007)
>   <sub>*(instead of **have a sandwich** and **lounge on the sofa**)*</sub>

Another ELU question, *[Which nouns can be used as verbs?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78354/which-nouns-can-be-used-as-verbs)*, will give you plenty of insight too.

Comment: Agreed. Before google was a verb it was a noun. This is the same sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

"To torture" is used here in the same way as "beat" in "I will beat some sense into you."

To this extent, "to torture [something] back [into her]" is not different from "I will put the gun back into the holster."

*To put back* in this sense = to return to its original/usual place.

"to torture some feelings back into her" - to torture her in order to return her feelings to their original/usual place.